# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails .Symfony2.8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, symfony

When i tried to update my database i got this error:

i'm not sure but I think the error means that the value for column tva_id on table fly
you are inserting doesn't exist on table tva. when i check in phpmyadmin tva`(`id`)) should be link to`(`tva_id`)` in table Post but is not. what should i do to fix this error ?

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE post ADD CONSTRAINT
>   FK_5     A8A6C8D4D79775F FOREIGN KEY (tva_id) REFERENCES tva (id)':
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update      a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`fly`.`#sql-93c_155`, CONSTRAI     NT `FK_5A8A6C8D4D79775F` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`tva_id`) REFERENCES `tva` (`id`))

Tva.php

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tva
 *
 * @ORM\Table("tva")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\TvaRepository")
 */
class Tva
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="multiplicate", type="float")
     */
    private $multiplicate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=125)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="float")
     */
    private $value;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set multiplicate
     *
     * @param float $multiplicate
     * @return Tva
     */
    public function setMultiplicate($multiplicate)
    {
        $this->multiplicate = $multiplicate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get multiplicate
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getMultiplicate()
    {
        return $this->multiplicate;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Tva
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set value
     *
     * @param float $value
     * @return Tva
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get value
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

post.php

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Tva", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $tva;

    /**
     *
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Security("user.getId() == post.getOwner()")
     */
    private $owner;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /*
     * @param User $owner
     */
    public function setOwner(User $owner)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Set tva
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Tva $tva
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTva(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Tva $tva)
    {
        $this->tva = $tva;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tva
     *
     * @return \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Tva 
     */
    public function getTva()
    {
        return $this->tva;
    }
}
```

user.php

```
<?php

namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser as BaseUser;
use ArrayIterator;
use Closure;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr\ClosureExpressionVisitor;

/**
 * This file has been generated by the Sonata EasyExtends bundle ( http://sonata-project.org/easy-extends )
 *
 */
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */


    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->commandes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $commandes;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

    /**
     * Add commandes
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     * @return User
     */
    public function addCommande(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes[] = $commandes;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Remove commandes
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes
     */
    public function removeCommande(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Commandes $commandes)
    {
        $this->commandes->removeElement($commandes);
    }

    /**
     * Get commandes
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCommandes()
    {
        return $this->commandes;
    }
}
```

Comment: i deleted all the data in my table post when i update my database it work. but when i completed the form in my index page and i submit i got again an error that telling me  'tva_id' cannot be null . how can i allow to submit data even tva_id is null ?

Comment: You explicitly set `nullable=false` to your column, thus causing the 'cannot be null' error.

Comment: @Artamiel oh yes your are right. i will set it to true. Thank you :)